# Morphia - How to ignore loading a property if it's of a certain type?

Tags: java, mongodb, morphia, odm

I have a legacy property in a MongoDB collection that's stored as a boolean, but that property has evolved and it's become an Object.

Is there a way in Morphia to ignore loading these properties when they are booleans? I'd just want to retrieve them if they are of the newer version (Object), if they are booleans I just want to ignore them.

When I try to find() a document with the property as a boolean, I get:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Boolean cannot be cast to com.mongodb.DBObject
>   ! at org.mongodb.morphia.mapping.EmbeddedMapper.fromDBObject(EmbeddedMapper.java:162) ~[morphia-1.0.1.jar:na]

Any thoughts? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `@PreLoad` annotation on a method and then remove that field from the `DBObject` if it's a boolean.  Then the subsequent handling of the `DBObject` should deserialize properly.  You can see an example [here](https://github.com/mongodb/morphia/blob/6dd903aa1d82cf7a8853498fc6b59d9298488e71/morphia/src/test/java/org/mongodb/morphia/TestDatastore.java#L462)

Comment: good news.  glad I could help.  before i had my breakfast even!  :D